# URL rewriting in ASP.NET 4.0 on radiobutton check event

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am trying to change URL of website and need help for the same. The scenario is that I have a search engine for student search and have different criteria for refine search. By  default I am showing all the student data on homepage and when we use search the result is displayed on the same page, so URL of the page does not change.

My search criteria are by date of join(1 month,2months,6months,1Yr) and state they belong from. I have added radio button for refine search, so on "OnCheckedChanged" event the data gets populated on the page. So now how do I change the URL so as to show something like, say I have website www.xyz.com and need to show www.xyz.com/bydate/1month or www.xyz.com/bystate/LA. Have googled many links but not able to understand how to start.

Below is snippet of my code

```
    <asp:DataList ID="dlJoin" CssClass="slider" r RepeatColumns="1" RepeatDirection="Vertical" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="dlJoin_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
<label style="text-align: left; margin-left:15px;">
<asp:RadioButton ID="rddlJoin" CssClass="radiobooking" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="rddlJoin_checkchanged" GroupName="rdGroupTag" runat="server" onKeyPress="return suppress(event);" /><%#Eval("Name")%>
</label>
<asp:Literal runat="server" Visible="false" ID="litdlJoin" Text='<%#Eval("Value")%>'></asp:Literal>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: And...... (64000 dollar question coming up) ....... what have you tried? Please add your code.

Comment: I have googled but I am not able to find how to change url on change events, not getting were to start from gone through many links like http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx    http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33341/URL-Rewriting-using-ASP-NET-for-SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with Javascript and not worry about redirecting on the server side(assuming that all your clients should have javascript). You can do a "pure" redirect by using something like

```
window.location.href = "http://xyz.com/bydate/1month";
```

This has equivalent behavior as to if you clicked on a link to that URL.

If you're wanting to use Ajax and make things be a bit nicer looking(and no full page loads) you can use a combination of `#` URL changes and using a tool like jQuery to easily load a `div` or some such from another URL